# Haskell: Avoiding heap overflow in tree+zipper construction

Tags: haskell, tree, heap-memory, overflow, zipper

I'm trying to implement a simple lexicon compression algorithm that uses Deterministic Finite Automaton as a data structure (actually it is Deterministic Acyclic Finite State Automaton, see [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton)). When I run the program against a large lexicon database (I have two datasets -- one contains ~900.000 unique words and the other ~4.000.000 unique words) I get a heap overflow:

```
mindfa.exe: Heap exhausted;
Current maximum heap size is 1073741824 bytes (1024 MB);
use `+RTS -M<size>' to increase it.
   6,881,239,544 bytes allocated in the heap
   4,106,345,528 bytes copied during GC
   1,056,362,696 bytes maximum residency (96 sample(s))
       6,884,200 bytes maximum slop
            1047 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     13140 colls,     0 par    2.14s    2.13s     0.0002s    0.0019s
  Gen  1        96 colls,     0 par   197.37s   199.06s     2.0736s    3.3260s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    2.54s  ( 12.23s elapsed)
  GC      time  190.09s  (191.68s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    9.42s  (  9.51s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time  202.05s  (203.91s elapsed)

  %GC     time      94.1%  (94.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,706,148,904 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity   1.3% of total user, 1.2% of total elapsed
```

My guess is that one of the problems is the laziness in `addWord` and `addWords` functions.

```hs
-- | Update the tree structure, starting from the current location.
addWord :: Zipper TnLabel -> B.ByteString -> Zipper TnLabel
addWord z s | B.null s = z
addWord (Zipper (DFA ts) parents) s = addWord z rest 
    where
        ch = B.head s
        rest = B.tail s
        pack defaultFlag = packTransitionLabel ch (if B.null rest then bit bitWordStop else defaultFlag)
        z = case break (\(w,_) -> getCh w == ch) ts of
            (_, []) -> Zipper
                { _focus = DFA []
                , _parents = (pack 0, [], ts) : parents
                }
            (left, (w, newFocus):right) -> Zipper
                { _focus = newFocus
                , _parents = ((pack w), left, right) : parents
                }

-- | Add a list of words to the DFA tree.
addWords :: Zipper TnLabel -> [B.ByteString] -> Zipper TnLabel
addWords z [] = z
addWords z (s:ss) = addWords z' ss
    where
        z' = addWord (root z) s
```

I have read about `seq`, `$!` and `!`, but still cannot see how I can use them in my example. How do I make the code strict(er)? On the other hand, maybe I'm using a wrong data structure (a tree + zipper)?

Here's a (not very) Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example of what I'm doing. When you run it, it should print out the number of states, the number of transitions and the whole DFA tree like this:

```
Lexicon
        State# 16
        Transition# 21
*
|
b--*
   |
   e--*
   |  |
   |  d!-*
   |     |
   |     s!-*
   |     |
   |     d--*
   |        |
   |        i--*
   |        |  |
   |        |  n--*
   |        |     |
   |        |     g!-*
   |        |
   |        e--*
   |           |
   |           d!-*
   |
   a--*
      |
      d!-*
         |
         n--*
         |  |
         |  e--*
         |     |
         |     s--*
         |        |
         |        s!-*
         |
         l--*
         |  |
         |  y!-*
         |
         a--*
            |
            s--*
               |
               s!-*
```

The code:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main (main) where 

import Prelude hiding (print)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B hiding (unpack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B (unpack) 
import Data.Word (Word8, Word16)
import Data.Bits ((.|.), (.&.), bit, complement, testBit)
import Foreign.Storable (sizeOf)
import Text.Printf hiding (fromChar, toChar)

--------------------------------------------- Deterministic finite automaton
type TnLabel = Word16

bitsInWord :: Int
bitsInWord = sizeOf (0::TnLabel) * 8

bitWordStop :: Int
bitWordStop = bitsInWord-1      -- ^ marks the end of a word

packTransitionLabel :: Word8 -> TnLabel -> TnLabel
packTransitionLabel ch flags = (flags .&. complement 0xFF) .|. fromIntegral ch

getCh :: TnLabel -> Word8
getCh w = fromIntegral $ w .&. 0xFF

type Transition e = (e, DFA e)

data DFA e = DFA [Transition e]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- DFA Zipper ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
data Zipper e = Zipper 
    { _focus :: DFA e
    , _parents :: [(e, [Transition e], [Transition e])]
    }
    deriving (Show)

-- Moving around ---------------------------------------------------------------
-- | The parent of the given location.
parent :: Zipper TnLabel -> Maybe (Zipper TnLabel)
parent (Zipper _ []) = Nothing
parent (Zipper focus ((event, left, right):parents)) = Just Zipper
    { _focus = DFA $ left++((event,focus):right)
    , _parents = parents
    }

-- | The top-most parent of the given location.
root :: Zipper TnLabel -> Zipper TnLabel
root z@(Zipper _ []) = z
root z = case parent z of
    Nothing -> z
    Just z2 -> root z2

-- Modification -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Update the tree structure, starting from the current location.
addWord :: Zipper TnLabel -> B.ByteString -> Zipper TnLabel
addWord z s | B.null s = z
addWord (Zipper (DFA ts) parents) s = addWord z rest 
    where
        ch = B.head s
        rest = B.tail s
        pack defaultFlag = packTransitionLabel ch (if B.null rest then bit bitWordStop else defaultFlag)
        z = case break (\(w,_) -> getCh w == ch) ts of
            (_, []) -> Zipper
                { _focus = DFA []
                , _parents = (pack 0, [], ts) : parents
                }
            (left, (w, newFocus):right) -> Zipper
                { _focus = newFocus
                , _parents = ((pack w), left, right) : parents
                }

-- | Add a list of words to the DFA tree.
addWords :: Zipper TnLabel -> [B.ByteString] -> Zipper TnLabel
addWords z [] = z
addWords z (s:ss) = addWords z' ss
    where
        z' = addWord (root z) s

-- Conversion ------------------------------------------------------------
empty :: Zipper TnLabel
empty = Zipper 
    { _focus = DFA []
    , _parents = []
    }

toDFA :: Zipper TnLabel -> DFA TnLabel
toDFA (Zipper dfa _) = dfa

fromList :: [B.ByteString] -> DFA TnLabel
fromList = toDFA . root . addWords empty

-- Stats ------------------------------------------------------------------
-- | Number of states in the whole DFA tree.
stateCount :: DFA TnLabel -> Int
stateCount = go 0
    where
        go acc (DFA []) = acc
        go acc (DFA ts) = go' (acc+1) ts
        go' acc [] = acc
        go' acc ((_,dfa):ts) = go 0 dfa + go' acc ts

-- | Number of transitions in the whole DFA tree.
transitionCount :: DFA TnLabel -> Int
transitionCount = go 0
    where
        go acc (DFA []) = acc
        go acc (DFA ts) = go' acc ts
        go' acc [] = acc
        go' acc ((_,dfa):ts) = go 1 dfa + go' acc ts

-- DFA drawing --------------------------------------------------------- 
draw' :: DFA TnLabel -> [String]
draw' (DFA ts) = "*" : drawSubTrees ts
    where 
        drawSubTrees [] = []
        drawSubTrees [(w, node)] = "|" : shift (toChar w : flagCh w : "-") "   " (draw' node)
        drawSubTrees ((w, node):xs) = "|" : shift (toChar w : flagCh w : "-") "|  " (draw' node) ++ drawSubTrees xs
        shift first other = zipWith (++) (first : repeat other)
        flagCh flags = if testBit flags bitWordStop then '!' else '-'
        toChar w = head . B.unpack . B.singleton $ getCh w

draw :: DFA TnLabel -> String
draw = unlines . draw'

print :: DFA TnLabel -> IO ()
print = putStr . draw

-- Main -----------------------------------------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let dfa = fromList ["bad", "badass", "badly", "badness", "bed", "bedded", "bedding", "beds"]
    printf "Lexicon\n"
    printf "\tState# %d\n" (stateCount dfa)
    printf "\tTransition# %d\n" (transitionCount dfa)
    print dfa
```

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to do any of the following; have you tried `-O` or `-O2` yet? The GHC optimizations include a "strictness analyzer" which can often sift through some of these things for you.

Regardless, laziness certainly seems like a likely culprit, and the first place that you'd start would be making the data structure strict by annotating its fields with `!` prefixes. So for example the `IntMap` type in `Data.IntMap` is just:

```
type Prefix = Int
type Mask   = Int
type Key    = Int
data IntMap a = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Prefix
                    {-# UNPACK #-} !Mask
                    !(IntMap a)
                    !(IntMap a)
              | Tip {-# UNPACK #-} !Key a
              | Nil
```

The "unpack" pragma tells GHC to store the integers directly in `Bin` and `Tip` rather than as a pointer to an object on the heap; the `!` tells GHC to immediately do whatever mathematics on them will convert them to a real integer; and the functions which manipulate the Prefix, Mask, and Key are ultimately the subject of `{-# INLINE ... #-}` pragmas which say, "hey, this isn't recursive", reducing those manipulations down to Prelude mathematics functions.

You might be surprised to know that actually, this code is *shared* between the Lazy and Strict IntMap cases. The `!(IntMap a)` only guarantees that the *structure of the tree* (and its keys, prefixes, and masks) is strict, but it still contains promises-to-compute its leaf elements if they've not already been computed. Doing this is **unnecessary in your case** (because you're not storing any information in the nodes) but is accomplished in `Data.IntMap.Strict` by peppering the functions which manipulate the nodes with `seq`:

```
insert :: Key -> a -> IntMap a -> IntMap a
insert k x t = k `seq` x `seq`
case t of
    ...
```

Read more about strictness [on the wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness).

Comment: I use `-O2 -prof -fprof-auto "-with-rtsopts=-M1G -p -s -hy -i0.1"` compile time options. Had a look at `Data.IntMap.Strict` source code. Changed data definitions for the tree and the zipper to `data DFA e = DFA ![Transition e]` and `data Zipper e = Zipper !(DFA e)
![(e, [Transition e], [Transition e])]` respectively. Still no luck (still getting _heap exhausted_ message)! Inlining seems to just removes detail (cost centre-wise) from the profile trace, without affecting the heap usage.

Comment: Okay, that's good. Notice that `![x]` is not actually noticeably more strict than `[x]` is, though. If you write `data F x = F {a :: x, b :: ![x]}` then the top-level `(:)` of that `b` is strict, but the rest is not. Writing `a (F 1 undefined)` will fail due to the `![Int]` strictness, but writing `a (F 1 (2:undefined))` will succeed because there is a `(:)` at the top. Data.Sequence and Data.Vector both have strict lists, I think, or you can roll you own; `data StrictList x = x :* !(Strictlist x) | Empty` should do it; use `:*` instead of `:` for pattern-matching on it.

Comment: Transformed all lists in my data types to `Data.Sequence`. So, now I have `data Transition e = Transition !e !(DFA e)`, `data DFA e = DFA (S.Seq (Transition e))`, `data Zipper e = Zipper !(DFA e) (S.Seq ((e, S.Seq (Transition e), S.Seq (Transition e))))`. I guess this as strict as I can get with the data types. Since I'm still getting heap overflow, I assume it is because of the laziness in the code for building up a DFA tree. I still wonder if I am using the right functional data structures for the intended application.